# Doctrine and Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, doctrine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I want to try the Google NoSQL solution, called Datastore, and I want to do that with symfony 2, because I don't want to have to make my own routing system.

My probleme is that in the official tutorial ( https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world ) they just use a MySQL solution.

So my question : do anyone know how to use the Datastore in place of the MySQL server here ?

Comment: I am also looking for kind of example of symfony with google datastore...